# Making a method in PHP automatically run some code after being called. Possible?

Tags: php, class, methods, automation

I'm not really sure if what I am looking for has a name, so it has been a bit difficult for me to search for, so I apologise if what I am asking has already been answered here before.

The situation is that I have an abstract class which has, of course, many other classes which extend it.

The abstract method in the abstract class is called `run()` and all of the extending classes define this method.

My problem is that I want to call some common code after the `run()` method has been called, but  I want to know if there is a better way to do this.

I could of course just paste my common code into each and every extending class's `run()` method, but if I do that then it would be a lot of work for me to make simple changes from that point onward.

I could also put my common code into a method in the parent class and then call if from the extending class's `run()` method with `$this`.

But my question is, is there a better way to do this, or do I have to either use the `$this` keyword or paste in the code into each class's?

Here is a small example of what I want to do with my current idea:

```
abstract class Parent_Class {
    public abstract function run();

    protected function common_code() {
        // Common code here
    }
}

class Child_Class {
    public function run() {
        // Code here
        // I want some common code to run after the run method has been called

        $this->common_code(); // Is this the best way to do it?
    }
}
```

Or is it possible to somehow tell the class that when the `run()` method has been called to automatically run the `common_code()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A far simpler way to do this would to simply have a third method which calls `run()` and then calls `common_code()`. Subclasses can then override `run()` all they want.

```
abstract class Parent_Class {
    public abstract function run();

    protected function common_code() {
        // Common code here
    }

    protected function start() {
        $this->run();
        $this->common_code();
    }

}

class Child_Class {
    public function run() {
        // Code here
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a very good point - I can't believe I didn't think of it... I'll leave this question open a bit longer to see if anyone else has different suggestions but after reading your answer it seems so obvious now.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Bradley Forster answer, you can define the method as protected, so when it's called from outside the class, you can intercept the event with php magic [__call](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) metod because

> __call() is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in an object context.

and then you can execute that method from the __call function

```
class A {

  public function __call($method, $args){

     if(!method_exists($this, $method))
       throw new Exception("Call to undefined method ".__CLASS__."::$method()");

     echo "doing something BEFORE function 'run' execution\n";

     $retval = call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $args);

     echo "doing something AFTER function 'run' execution\n";

     return $retval;
  }

  protected function run() {
      echo "function 'run' executed\n" ;
  }
}

$a = new A;
$a->run();
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by Amber is nice and simple. But requires you to put your data in `run()` but call `start()`. Here is an alternative that allows you to have your code `$a->run()` in all your scripts, and `$a->run()` with your common code, but encapsulated in a namespace.

File hooks.php

```
<?php
// File: hooks.php
namespace hook;

class processHooks {
    public function __construct() { /* Fatal Error without constructor */ }

    protected function processHooks($_c, $method, $args) {
        /* Swap the next two callbacks to run your custom code after */
        call_user_func_array("\hook\\{$_c}::{$method}", $args);
        return call_user_func_array(array($_c,$method), $args);
    }
}

class A {
    public function foo() {
        echo 'Doing code stuff BEFORE calling child function....<br>';
    }
}
```

File regular_file.php

```
<?php
// File: regular_file.php
include "hooks.php";

class A extends \hook\processHooks {

    /* All that is required is this function
     * and the function with common code to be protected
     */
    public function __call($method, $args) {
        self::processHooks(__CLASS__, $method, $args);
    }

    protected function foo() {
        echo 'Method is called....<br>';
    }
}

$a = new A();
$a->foo();
```

This works beacause method *foo* of class *A* in *regular_file.php* is protected, so it's not callable outside the class, so calling it triggers PHP magic method [__call](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call)

> __call() is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in an object context.

Comment: This is a simplified version of a system I designed using all static functions.It can be easily changed back if that's how you want to use it.